# Convert a list of characters in a single List , using a List comprehension

Tags: python, list

I have this list :
`listOfWords = ["this","is","a","list","of","words"]`
and I need to have `[this is a list of words]`, with a List comprehension.

Comment: you want a list containing a single string? `[" ".join(listOfWords)]`

Comment: What is the output that you want?  `['this is a list of words']`?

Comment: Yes I will [" ".join(listOfWords)]

Comment: and the output ['this is a list of words']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean a list with a single string item?

```
>>> [' '.join(["this","is","a","list","of","words"])]
['this is a list of words']
```

Comment: yes , I using idle console

Comment: Python is Python everywhere, which IDE or console doesn't really matter :P

Comment: But I have to write :

Comment: If you wonder about `>>>`, no you don't type that in, you just type `[' '.join(["this","is","a","list","of","words"])]`

Comment: sorry ... I have to write :    listOfWords = ["this","is","a","list","of","words"]

ls = listOfWords

[' '.join(ls)]

print ls
And I come ['this', 'is', 'a', 'list', 'of', 'words'] , sorry I am new in Python ...